# Can't set serviceAccountKey for Cloud Firestore with Python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am trying to access to the Cloud Firestore db of my Firebase project. I have a very simple code, I just want to connect to my database and add something to it, but unfortunately I can't set the `serviceAccountKey` properly, therefore I get the following error:

```
raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE)
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or
explicitly create credential and re-run the application. For more
information, please see
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials.
```

Of course I understand this message and I have visited [the Google Developers link](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials), but I didn't find anything that could be useful in my case.

It must be added that I am trying [this Firebase tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yylnC3dr_no), so I followed its example code and it does the verification with `serviceAccountKey.json` file.

So here is my code that gives the error:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

cred = credentials.Certificate('serviceAccountKey.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()

doc_ref = db.collection(u'dev').document(u'alovelace')
doc_ref.set({
    u'first': u'Ada',
    u'last': u'Lovelace',
    u'born': 1815
})
```

I have tried out two different account keys, downloaded from two different places inside the Firebase admin. I assume the right one is that I found at the `Settings > Service Accounts > Firebase Admin SDK` - So I have downloaded the generated key, copied to my apps folder and renamed it to serviceAccountKey.json, then ran the code and got the error from the top of the question.

Have I made an obvious mistake in my code? What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: The above code works fine for me. Can you try to locate the line that triggers the above error? You can also try `print(firebase_admin.get_app().credential)` to see if the service account credential has been picked up by the SDK.

Comment: Thanks @HiranyaJayathilaka, I could log it with your snippet, and I figured out the set() method was wrong somehow. So I used the official docs to recreate the adding method and it's fine now.

Comment: @rihe you could post an answer to this question now that you found a solution!